# Displaying Result of two compared arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, string, concatenation

Maybe I just need to step away but I have been staring at this code and I cannot figure out what I need to do. I am comparing submitted responses (in a text file), against an answer key (separate text file) that have been written into arrays. I have used a for loop to compare the arrays and I have the count of how many correct answers and incorrect answers.

I'm trying to display the specific question numbers (index number) of the submitted responses that are incorrect in a label. I have tried a for loop, a foreach, and various methods with strings and arrays. I'm not sure if the problem is in the original for loop that is comparing the arrays or if it has to with the way I am trying to display the string with concatenation. Sorry if the answer is staring me in the face and I am missing it.

```
private void buttonGrade_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] correct = new string[20];
            string[] wrong = new string[20];
            string[] result = new string[20];

            string corAns = "";
            string incorAns = "";

            StreamReader inputFile;
            StreamReader staticFile;
            inputFile = File.OpenText("Response.txt");
            staticFile = File.OpenText("Answers.txt");
            int count = 0;
            string response = "";
            string answers = "";
                        
            

            int strAcount = 0; //Counter for correct answers
            int strRcount = 0; //Counter for incorrect answers
           
            while (inputFile.EndOfStream == false && staticFile.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                response = inputFile.ReadLine();
                answers = staticFile.ReadLine();
                correct[count] = response;
                wrong[count] = answers;
                count++;
            }


            for (int j = 0; j < correct.Length; j++)
            {
                if (correct[j] == wrong[j])
                {

                    corAns += 1;
                    strAcount = corAns.Length;
                }
                else
                {
                    incorAns += 1;
                    strRcount = incorAns.Length;
                }
            }

            if (strAcount > 14)
            {
                labelOutputpassfail.Text = "Pass";
            }
            else
            {
                labelOutputpassfail.Text = "Fail";
            }

            inputFile.Close();
            staticFile.Close();

            string myString = "#s - ";
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i += strRcount)
            {
                myString += incorAns.ToString() + ", ";
            }
            labelOutputmissed.Text = myString;
            
            labelOutputcorrect.Text = strAcount.ToString();
            labelOutputincorrect.Text = strRcount.ToString();

            
           
        }
```

Comment: the inCorAns variable is set as the number of incorrect answers, you would be just printing the same thing over until i < 20. If you want the index of questions that were incorrect, you could save the the loop counter j in the first loop (where the answer and responses are verified) into a list, and just print those values.

Comment: I really appreciate the quick response. Ultimately that's what I'm trying to do but I don't have much experience with List, but I'm working on that approach now. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Yes, you should step back and rethink your approach to the problem. First you really are not specifying “what” is not working. I suggest you debug the code to help you. And break the problem down in to pieces… For starters, are you 100% sure the arrays are getting filed from the files? From what I can see, I question if the first `while` loop is ever entered. Meaning the arrays will be empty. After that, the code needs explaining. It appears you are making this far more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: @JohnG I apologize - I added in the missing code above the while loop. I'm sure I am going down the a complicated path, but this is my first every programming course so working through the structure I know thus far. 75% of the code is doing coming out correct. The for loop at the end after the file closes produces #s - 1111,1111, etc. I'm trying to get it to display the number within the index that is producing a wrong answer, i.e. #s - 3, 8, 11, etc.

Comment: Since you are learning, I highly recommend you learn how to debug and trace your code. The are many examples. Assuming the arrays have data, you need to step-through the code in the `for` loop…  `for (int j = 0; j < correct.Length; j++) { …` … and look closer at what the code is doing… specifically the two lines of code in the `if` comparison statement… `if (correct[j] == wrong[j])` … let us assume they ARE equal and the code executes the two lines of code… `corAns += 1;` … and … `strAcount = corAns.Length;` … ? … this is very odd….

Comment: It appears you have theses assignments crossed up. `corAns` is a `STRING` … and that is why you get the output…   “1111,1111” … with each iteration of the loop with a correct answer… another STRING “1” is added to `corAns`… ? … and the other line of code… `strAcount = corAns.Length;` … is very odd because `strAcount` is an `int` and I am mystified as to what `corAns.Length` has to do with “counting” how many correct answers there are. You need to explain what those two lines of code are supposed to be doing.

Comment: Also, you have a possible endless loop in the `for` statement … `for (int i = 0; i < 20; i += strRcount)` … ? … the increment is very strange … `i += strRcount` … ? … this may work if the response file misses at least ONE answer, however, if the response file has ALL the correct answers, then… `strRCount` will be zero (0)… so the increment value will be zero (0) and the loop never ends.

Comment: I appreciate your patience and the feedback on this. I also corrected the `for` statement that was `i+= strRcount` and have changed it to `i++`. I've managed to get to the point where `incorAns` now populates with the output I expect. However because it is a string as you pointed out I am simply getting all of the answers in one (2391415) instead of (2,3,9,14,15). I think my problem now lies in my arrays vs strings which I'm going through line by line. But your insights helped pull me out of the weeds big time.

Comment: Arrays and strings are two different things. You could do what you want without using any arrays at all. However, I am betting that this is a school assignment where the subject is arrays. So, you are stuck in doing it the way it was assigned. I suggest you clearly state what the requirements are and where you are stuck. It looks like one hurdle is cleared and that is filling both arrays with the data from the files. Next you want to loop through those arrays and compare values and keep track of the right and wrong answers.

Comment: Looking at your current code after the arrays are filled and you start the `for` loop through the arrays… is well… it is pretty clear that something is not right in that `for` loop. Stepping through the code would easily reveal the problems you describe. I could proffer a solution; however, I am confident you can figure it out on your own. With that said… rethink your logic in the `for` loop (KISS) and if you cannot get it to work, then [edit] your question with the updated code.

Comment: Also, I suggest you name your variables better to make it clear what they are for. Remember this naming is not only for you but anyone else who reads it… like your teacher and helpers on SO. Lastly, I suggest you take a look at the [StringBuilder Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0) ... it can be quite useful especially when you want to build a big string inside a loop. From your last comment, the only things missing are the commas. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the index of the incorrect answer 3,8,11..etc, but declared corAns as string so this will not increment, it will only concatenate. From your code I'm assuming you want to compare a (submitted array of responses - inputFile) and you want to validate it against a (array of correct answers - staticFile), then produce and result array of the index of incorrect responses. This is how I would go about writing the code:

```
inputFile = File.OpenText("Response.txt");
staticFile = File.OpenText("Answers.txt");
string[] response = new string[];
string[] answers = new string[];
string[] result = new string[];

foreach(string r in inputFile) {
response += r;
}
foreach(string a in staticFile) {
answers += a;
}

if(response.Length == answers.Length) {
for(int i=0; i<response.Length; i++) {
//get incorrect answer index and add to string result
if(!response[i].Equals(answers[i])) {
result += i.ToString();
   }
  }
}
return result.ToArray();
```

Also if you want a one liner Linq is a good way to go:

```
string[] result = response.Except(answers);
```